# UITableview footer goes out of bounds while adding a tableview using autolayout programatically

Tags: ios, ios7, autolayout

Below is my code

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];


    UITableView *myTableview = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero style:UITableViewStylePlain];
    myTableview.dataSource = self;
    myTableview.delegate = self;
    myTableview.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    [self.view addSubview:myTableview];

    NSLayoutConstraint* widthConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:myTableview attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0];
    NSLayoutConstraint* heightConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:myTableview attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0];
    NSLayoutConstraint* topConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:myTableview attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0];
    NSLayoutConstraint* leftConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:myTableview attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0];

    [self.view addConstraints:@[widthConstraint,heightConstraint,topConstraint,leftConstraint]];

    UIView* footerView = [[UIView alloc] init];
    footerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    [myTableview setTableFooterView:footerView];
    footerView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0, 320, 60);


}
]
```

Comment: The thing about autolayout (and why I don't prefer to use it) is that it doesn't give you a whole lot of flexibility when this kind of thing happens.

Comment: I ended up changing the contentinset when the tableview is scrolled to the bottom ...

Comment: That'll work, just make sure you're not hardcoding the numbers so you don't create a headache for yourself when doing another interface orientation. :)